# Can't clear cache Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, caching, routes

I changed my routes and removed some fields in form type, but when I go new route I get message that route match this does not exists and when I go to old I see my form with fields what I removed. Clearing cache not help. Where is my problem?

Comment: Sometimes using `console cache:clear` on the command line doesn't work, and leaves certain files behind.  Have you manually cleared the `app/cache` directories directly on the file system?

Comment: yes, I run this `rm -rf app/cache/*`

Comment: Are you using `APC`? Try either clearing APC cache or restarting httpd...

Answer (score 0):

Try : "php app/console router:debug" to see if symfony see your routes

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#visualizing-debugging-routes

Comment: Plz add some more details too